# Add/Remove OpportunityPartner Role Values displayed in picklist?

Tags: apex, opportunity, sales-cloud

How can we update the OpportunityPartner Role values that are displayed? So far I have:

- Setup > Accounts > Partner Roles and then updated the values... This doesn't seem to effect opportunity partners
- Setup > Object Manager and typed in "Partner" and there's no object that I can find called Opportunity Partner.

The goal is to add an Opportunity Partner role called **"Vendor"**

Comment: isn't this done with the Reverse Role value?

Comment: @cropredy The reverse value role is "Client" for us. But nonetheless, I still cannot update the values. I deactived the account partner roles and nothing has changed on the opportunitypartner roles picklist.

Comment: are you trying to update values in existing records or just add a new Account<>Opportunity partner role/reverse role combo?  I will point out that I long since abandoned using this feature, preferring my own custom junction object

Comment: @cropredy Thats what I am going to do too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of challenges with the OOTB Account/Opportunity Partners.

- A mentally confusing setup of role and reverse role
- The roles can only be defined /edited in Classic (as of V57)
- You can't add any custom fields to the junction record between Account and Opportunity
- There is nomenclature confusion with another SFDC feature `Account Roles` that is used in Experience Clouds

All that being said, I long since abandoned using this feature, preferring my own custom junction object where I could add custom fields, define the relationship names, etc.  I recommend you do as well.